# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть проблема, что если быстро обновлять страницу, то крашится скрипт, то есть падает нода, с сообщением:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Я так понимаю скрипт не успевает получать данные с респонса, как исправить проблему?

```
function test(){
  helf.send("clientlist", function(err, response){  
    response.forEach(function(response) {
       socket.emit('test123', { name: response.client_nickname, cid: response.cid });
    });
   });
 }
setInterval(function() { test() }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вы неправы. У вас при вызове `helf.send("clientlist",` возникает ошибка, о чем вас и уведомляют в параметре `err`, а параметр `response` остается пустым.  Но, поскольку вы `err` не проверяете - получилось что получилось.